# MongoDB query result is strange

Tags: json, mongodb

I used Aggregation FrameWork of MongoDB. However, result was strange.
Some are arrayed json data and other is not arrayed json data.

The query is :

```
> db.employees.aggregate([ {$group : {_id:"$deptno", enames:{$addToSet : "$ename"}} },
                                     {$sort:{_id:1}} ]).forEach(printjson)
```

The result is :

```
{ "_id" : 10, "enames" : [ "CLERK", "PRESIDENT", "CLARK" ] }  
{
    "_id" : 20,
    "enames" : [
        "FORD",
        "ADAMS",
        "JONES",
        "SCOTT",
        "SMITH"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 30,
    "enames" : [
        "TURNER",
        "BLAKE",
        "WARD",
        "MARTIN",
        "JAMES",
        "ALLEN"
    ]
}
```

`{"_id" : 10}` is not arrayed json data. However, `{"_id" : 20}` and `{"_id" : 30}` are arrayed json data.

I don't know what's wrong with it. Is forEach(printjson) wrong?

Comment: do you see any error with command?

Comment: @Astro No, I didn't see any errors with command.

Comment: what do you mean by {"_id" : 10} is not json. However, {"_id" : 20} and {"_id" : 30} are json type.?

Comment: @Astro Ah, I wrote wrong. Sorry. Its meaning is to represent in the same form as {"_id":20} and {"_id":30}. {"_id":10} is not arrayed json data. I will modify the contents of the text.

Comment: It looks like all of your `enames` values are arrays, with the only difference being the formatting of the first document. Is that the difference you are referring to? If so, this is just a display issue: the first document fits on a single output line but the following documents do not so are wrapped onto multiple lines. What specific client app and version are you using to view this result?

Comment: @Stennie  Yes! I want the first document to apper like the second document and third document. I followed examples of books. The book of mongoDB version is 2.0.6. But My computer mongoDB version is 3.4.4.

Comment: @Stennie I'm sorry. I wrote the wrong setence. MongoDB version of the book is 2.0.6.